# Data structure for unique element storage

Tags: list, perl, unique, xs

I'm looking for a data structure which should preferably perform equal O(1)? for any number of elements when adding/removing/retrieving elements.

Here are some additional guidelines,

- retrieving elements should not involve slow `keys()`
- elements must be always unique and defined
- element order is not significant
- addition or removal of element should not involve iteration over other elements
- gaps in retrieved list of elements are tolerable and can be represented with `undef` value

Please suggest better solution than,

```
sub uniqArrayFactory {
  my $members = [];
  my $seen = {};
  my $gaps = [];

  return sub {
    my (%arg) = @_;

    return $members if $arg{members};
    my $m;
    if (defined ($m = $arg{del})) {

      return if !$seen->{$m};
      ${ $seen->{$m} } = undef;
      push @$gaps, delete($seen->{$m});
    }
    elsif (defined ($m = $arg{add})) {

      return if $seen->{$m};
      if (@$gaps) {
        $seen->{$m} = pop @$gaps;
        ${ $seen->{$m} } = $m;
      }
      else {
        push @$members, $m;
        $seen->{$m} = \( $members->[-1] );
      }
    }
    return $m;
  };
}
```

**UPDATE** (usage)

```
my $fa = uniqArrayFactory();

$fa->(add => 10);
$fa->(del => 10);
my $members = $fa->(mebers => 1);
```

Comment: Can you add some examples of how you would call that please?

Comment: @simbabque please check update.

Comment: ... am I being dense, or are you describing a hash?

Comment: @Sobrique yes I am, but currently not happy with `keys` performance, and it would get invoked a lot.

Comment: I'm sure you won't be able to write something in Perl that is faster than the built-in `keys` operator, which is written in C. I think you need to explain more about what you're doing that is giving you unacceptable performance. `keys` is a trivial operation and does little more than return a pre-existing list of C strings reformatted as Perl scalars

Comment: @Borodin returning the ready array ref `$members` is faster as `return [keys %$seen]`. So, if the factory must be very fast for the `$factory->(members => 1)` then the `keys` isn't the fastest solution.

Comment: keys() is very far from O(1), not to mention what jm666 wrote. I see this as a worthy memory/speed tradeoff in case when elements are often being retrieved.

Comment: At some point, you will iterate the member array which is O(n) anyway. So I don't understand why you insist on returning the member array in O(1).

Comment: @nwellnhof that is a valid point so I did some benchmarks which include member iteration, https://gist.github.com/mpapec/29198302b7cca8d3c74be45ff4b12230 (`keys()` and a few flavors of `each()`) and differences are significant.

Comment: @Сухой27 Interesting, I didn't realize that `keys` and `each` are so slow. `for my $v (keys %hash1)` is a bit faster but still considerably slower than your uarray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keys` and `each` are surprisingly slow indeed. But if you store each element as a value of a hash and use `values`, things get a low faster. With

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw(:all);

my $i;
my $fa;
my %hash;

my %compare = (
  uarray => sub {
    $fa->(add => $i++);
    my $memb = $fa->(members => 1);
    for my $v (@$memb) { next if !defined $v; }
  },
  hash => sub {
    $hash{ $i } = $i;
    for my $v (values %hash) {}
    $i++;
  },
);

$i = 0; $fa = uniqArrayFactory(); %hash = ();
cmpthese(10000, \%compare);

sub uniqArrayFactory {
  my $members = [];
  my $seen = {};
  my $gaps = [];

  return sub {
    my (%arg) = @_;

    return $members if exists $arg{members};
    my $m;
    if (defined ($m = $arg{del})) {

      return if !$seen->{$m};
      ${ $seen->{$m} } = undef;
      push @$gaps, delete($seen->{$m});
    }
    elsif (defined ($m = $arg{add})) {

      return if $seen->{$m};
      if (@$gaps) {
        $seen->{$m} = pop @$gaps;
        ${ $seen->{$m} } = $m;
      }
      else {
        push @$members, $m;
        $seen->{$m} = \( $members->[-1] );
      }
    }
    return $m;
  };
}
```

I get:

```
         Rate   hash uarray
hash   3205/s     --    -6%
uarray 3401/s     6%     --
```

Comment: Great to see `values()` performing much better, although performance gap is greater on `v5.20.3` (above 20%). Which perl version did you use?

Comment: I was using 5.18 on OS X. With 5.22 on Ubuntu I get -13% and 15%.

Answer (score 1):

Ironically, maybe [`Tie::IxHash`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::IxHash), which was motivated by the desire to retrieve the keys of a hash in a specified order, is as close as you're going to get to what you want.

In [the `Tie::IxHash` implementation](https://metacpan.org/source/CHORNY/Tie-IxHash-1.23/lib/Tie/IxHash.pm), keys and values are stored in array references. `keys` returns a copy of the set of keys, but something like `(tied %hash)->[1]` would give you direct access to it.

Removing elements in a `Tie::IxHash` is O(n). A possible workaround for that would be to replace values with `undef` rather than deleting them. That is, preferring

```
$ixhash{$obsolete_key} = undef;
```

to

```
delete $ixhash{$obsolete_key};
```

Or if you were able to pool your deletions -- if you could organize your code so that you usually called `delete` on several keys around the same time and in between other operations on the hash -- then there are opportunities for improving on `Tie::IxHash`.